# How can I clean merge my new version of code with old one without using `-f` flag?

Tags: java, git, github

I have working on local brach in my computer; moreover, I have one public Github account. The only author of the code, as you guess, is me. Whenever I want to `git push origin master`, I get `you should merge before pushing` error, so I always does `pull origin master` and then `git add .. & git commit -m "merged`. However, this lines of code sucks my code. In other words, in my code, I see `<<<<<<<<<head`, `hash code` and merged version of old and new code in same file. Even if I am only author, my Github account does not recognize my past and always pushes me to merge the old version with new version in the same file. Moreover, automatically, add `<<<<<<<head` sort of lines in my code. How can I **clean merge**, no `<<<<head` sort of things or no merging old with new one in same file, my new version of code with old one ( not to prefer using without using `-f` flag)?

I am using Git shell in Windows.

Comment: From what I see, you should definitely read a bit about Git : http://git-scm.com/book/en

Comment: You're getting *merge conflicts*, which must be resolved manually. It's not clear from what you wrote where they are coming from. But Git instructs you on resolving conflicts as you go. Instead of blindly doing `git add . && git commit -m "merged"`, use `git status` to see what status your repository is actually in. By `add`ing conflicted files you are marking them as "conflict resolved" without actually resolving anything.

Comment: @ddr2 do you have recommendation which chapter should I read to fix my  error? OR, briefly, say how to solve it. Thanks

Comment: The first three are a must-read for any beginner with git :) As for how to solve your current issue, Chris' commentary briefly explains what is going on and how you can fix it.